# Convert [*]u8 to []u8 in Zig

Tags: pointers, zig

When I have a `[*]u8` pointer and a `usize` length, how do I convert the pointer to a `[]u8` slice with the specified length?

Answer (score 8):

Use the slice syntax on the `[*]u8` pointer:

```
fn to_slice(pointer: [*]u8, len: usize) []u8 {
    return pointer[0..len];
}
```